# How to move/copy/process files based upon any extended attributes in Terminal/shell?

Tags: terminal, command-line, automator, extended-attributes

I need to move a number of files based on various extended attributes, but it's not clear how to test and take action based on these. For a basic example, what if I were to want to find and move all files in a folder that have the `com.apple.quarantine` to `~/Downloads/quarantined/` and files with `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` to `~/Downloads/sort/`?

Clearly one might think, first execute a command such as these, but will see that the results need further processing:

```
$ /bin/ls -ldO@ *
-rw-r--r--@ 1 USER  GROUP  - 123456789 Jul  8 10:52 FILENAME.EXT
    com.apple.quarantine          54
-rw-r--r--@ 1 USER  GROUP  - 123456789 Jul  4 15:26 FILENAME_2.EXT
    com.apple.quarantine          59
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms         65
    ETC      XX
```

`xattr` isn't much better insomuch that it offers similarly convoluted results:

```
$ xattr *
FILENAME.EXT: com.apple.quarantine
FILENAME_2.EXT: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
FILENAME_2.EXT: com.apple.quarantine
FILENAME_2.EXT: ETC
```

Is there another / more clean and efficient way of moving files based on attributes vs writing a script that obtains and then processes the files based upon various extended filesystem attribute fields on macOS?

Comment: How do you expect a file with both attributes in your example to be treated?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal, let's assume the current directory you are in is the directory you would like to search for the files with the attribute `com.apple.quarantine`.

This following shell script will find and move the files.

```
find "$PWD" -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -xattrname com.apple.quarantine -exec mv {} ~/Downloads/quarantined/ \;
```